# check if a particular method is invoked/executed during runtime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, runtime, invoke

Looking for a way to find out if a particular method is being executed during runtime in Javascript if the method exists in a direct package dependency in production /development server dynamically.

Comment: Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: well, what I meant, in production.

Comment: Add a log entry.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for code that you can control/update, you can track access by defining `getters` for the method's context:

```js
const logs = [];
const appObject = {
  get multiply(){
    logs.push(`accessed multiply: ${Date()}`)
    return (valA, valB) => valA * valB;
  }
};

const result = appObject.multiply(2,3);

console.log(result);
console.log(logs);
```

Comment: oh, interesting, but that requires modifying the whole code. is there a way to do this globally without modifying each method?

Comment: There's not really any way to do that; this is only available as basically a design decision.